# How can we avoid forking the java process in a Spring Boot executable JAR?

Tags: spring-boot

The default Spring Boot executable script will fork the Java process when executing the JAR. However, we require the Java process to have the same PID that as is launched by executing the start script. (This is because of something else we have to operate with.)

Is there a way we can, say, prepend "exec" to the Java command in order to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried: nohup java -jar $D_ARGS app.jar? I always get single PID

Comment: We can (though we're using exec rather than nohup), but it loses some of the customizations we've inlined to the embedded start script.